# How to play sound with Pyqt5 QtMultimedia?

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
def play_tts(self,file_path):
   file = open(file_path)
   mixer.init()
   mixer.music.load(file)
   mixer.music.play()
   while mixer.music.get_busy():
       time.sleep(0.03)
       if window.ttsIs:
           break
   mixer.stop()
   mixer.quit()
   file.close()
   remove(file_path)
```

How do I write the above code with QtMultimedia?

Can you give me a example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file is a .wav then just use QSound:

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtMultimedia

CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


def main():
    filename = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "beal.wav")

    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

    QtMultimedia.QSound.play(filename)


    # end in 5 seconds:
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(5 * 1000, app.quit)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you want to play more formats then you should use QMediaPlayer:

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtMultimedia

CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


def main():
    filename = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "sound.mp3")

    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

    player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()

    def handle_state_changed(state):
        if state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            print("started")
        elif state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.StoppedState:
            print("finished")
            QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit()

    player.stateChanged.connect(handle_state_changed)

    url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)
    player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(url))
    player.play()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I want if the sound is playing, i want wait the process. How can i do this? Like mixer.music.get_busy()

Comment: @KutaN I recommend you forget about the while loops with Qt since you are going to block the eventloop, instead you must use the signals, in this case the stateChanged signal of the QMediaPlayer is enough, see my update. In this the similar to `mixer.music.get_busy()` is  `player.state() == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.PlayingState`

Comment: `player.state() == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.PlayingState` is does not work. While loop is not finish. I need to finishing with boolean variable.

Comment: @KutaN It seems that you have not read my previous comment, you should not use while-loop, use the signals, for example change the state of the flag in `print("started")` and `print("finished")`